# How to iterate and create DOM elements with js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used to do this using javascript frameworks like ReactJS and Angular. But I am thinking how could i achieve this through pure js or even with jQuery.
I want to make a dynamic `Select` list. Suppose I have the values in an array as follow:

```
const data= ['Elment 1','Elment 2','Elment 3','Elment 4','Elment 5','Elment 6','Elment 7'];
```

and In html I want to iterate over the `Option` in the drop down select list

```
<select>
     //LOOP OVER THIS OPTION TO DISPLAY THE VALUES OF THE data array
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `append` on the `<select>` element in question, pass in the array of values mapped to select `Option` objects.

```js
const data = ['Elment 1','Elment 2','Elment 3','Elment 4','Elment 5','Elment 6','Elment 7'];

$('#dynamic-select').append(data.map((text, index) => new Option(text, index)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dynamic-select"></select>
```

But you do not really need jQuery to do this. With ES6, you can use the spread operator.

```js
const data = ['Elment 1','Elment 2','Elment 3','Elment 4','Elment 5','Elment 6','Elment 7'];

document.querySelector('#dynamic-select')
  .append(...data.map((text, index) => new Option(text, index)));
```

```html
<select id="dynamic-select"></select>
```

---

### jQuery magic

The PURE jQuery way:

```js
const data = ['Elment 1','Elment 2','Elment 3','Elment 4','Elment 5','Elment 6','Elment 7'];

const $sel = $('#dynamic-select');

$.each(data, (index, item) => {
  $('<option>', {
    text: item,
    val: index
  }).appendTo($sel);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dynamic-select"></select>
```

As a jQuery plugin:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.populateSelect = function(data, options) {
    let opts = $.extend({}, options);
    return this.append(data.map((item, index) => {
      return (function(isObject) {
        return $('<option>', {
          text  : isObject ? item.text : item,
          value : isObject ? item.value : (opts.valueAsText ? item : index)
        });
      })($.isPlainObject(item));
    }));
  };
})(jQuery);

const data = ['Elment 1','Elment 2','Elment 3','Elment 4','Elment 5','Elment 6','Elment 7'];

const $sel = $('#dynamic-select').populateSelect(data, { valueAsText : true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dynamic-select"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const data = ['Elment 1', 'Elment 2', 'Elment 3', 'Elment 4', 'Elment 5', 'Elment 6', 'Elment 7'];

var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.innerHTML = data[i];
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: They asked for jQuery, so you should have created the `option` element with: `let $sel = $("#mySelect");` and inside the for-loop: `$('<option>', { text: data[i], value: i }).appendTo($sel)`.

Comment: The question says "with js or jQuery".